# what can you say about the solutions of the equation $y' = x^2+y^2$ just by looking at the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can we say that the graph is symmetric about origin. Because replacing $x$, $y$ with $-x$, $-y$ does not change the equation

Also the slope becomes larger as we move away from origin.

Anything else that you guys can conclude?

Thanks

Comment: The slope is always positive? There's an extrema at the origin whose nature you can find by substituting $(0,0)$ into the second derivative.

Comment: This is a standard example for a Riccati equation.  See [Riccati D.E., vertical asymptotes](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2348022/115115) and the related topics in the right sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of a circle about the origin is $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, for radius $r$. So we see that the rate $y'$ is constant along such circles. That's just one observation I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

1) Solutions are increasing.

2) The graph is *not* in general symmetric around the origin, it's only symmetric (odd) if $y(0)=0$.

3) The slope of the entire family is constant on concentric circles.

4) The solution (starting at $x=0$) grows faster than $y(0)+x^3/3$ and also faster than $y(0)/(1-xy(0))$. From the second property, we know it has poles.